# XAMPP-Apache is not running

Tags: xampp

I have xampp on Red Hat Linux
when I start httpd service I get this message
**Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName.**
and when I start xampp I get this message 
**XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.**
any possible help

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an error. Your apache is started in first attempt.

I usually get warning "Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName" when I start my apache. But my apache starts perfectly.

More here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name